# Angular 8 - showing a loading spinner only within the component

Tags: angular, signalr, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I am building a SPA where the homepage will include multiple components. I would like to have a loading spinner for each components, without an overlay and only showing within the component.

I have implemented `ng-http-loader 6.0.1`, but it created an overlay and the spinner is shown over the whole page. I did not find any option which would force it stay within that specific component.

If not, what would be the best way? Hardcode the spinner and when the `http` request returns the result, replace the spinner with the results? I think there must be a better way of doing this.

Example `http` call which is using `@angular/common/http HttpClient`:

```
private startHttpRequest = () => {
this.http.get('/TestUrl/')
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

}

I am using `SignalR` to display and update the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is an easy method to achieve the component level spinner:**

1. Create a small component called '**Spinner**'.
2. Include spinner inside the components that make web service requests
3. Control the visibility of the Spinner component using 
   **ng-hide** or **ng-show**

Comment: how would this go if I am making api calls in parent component and passing this returned data using @Input properties.. and only make spinner available for child component for which the data has been fetched ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the progress from material:

https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview
https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview

with your own css styles in app.component:

```
 <div class="loading-overlay" *ngIf="loading">
  <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" value="40" color="accent"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

by default, the material progress don't overlay the page, you need to create a css class if you want to

Comment: Thanks cucuru. I am going to use this spinner with the logic below

Comment: Whilst this answer in theory works, the author never mentioned the use of material. And material is a massive library to implement for the save of solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A loading spinner is simply css, and most packages assume you want the whole screen covered. Your best best would be to create your own CSS for said spinner, then in your component you can do something like...

```
<div *ngIf="myLogic === true" class="mycssspinner">
    <span class="spinner">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

Then define mycsssponner inside your stylessheet. There are many examples of pure CSS spinners online [(example from first google result)](https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/). You can do this with a component, but this is the most lightweight, easily re-usable way to achieve what you want.